# Как обойти Access-Control-Allow-Origin если идет POST запрос к чужому серверу (https)?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

CORS, JSONP не помогает т.к. нет доступа к чужому серверу. Если сделать запрос через онлайн сервисы реквестов, то они благополучно возвращают результат. Подскажите как можно еще попробовать?

Comment: Это ограничение - только ограничение браузера. Вы можете спокойно делать **POST** запрос с сервера.

Answer (score 1):

Была подобная ситуация с одним смс сервисом. Попробуйте на своем сервере добавить промежуточный файл php, который будет принимать Ваш post запрос, затем отсылать post на целевой сервер, принимать ответ и отсылать Вам ответ.

Comment: Уже делаю так только через node.js , пока ничего не ругается)